# Error in AWS Schema Conversion Tool - Invalid Table Mappings document

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-dms

I am trying to create a DMS task in SCT, but I get the following error - My source is SQLServer and my target is MySQL DB v 5.7.23.

[image]

Here is the generated mappings JSON:

```json
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule-type": "selection",
      "rule-id": "1",
      "rule-name": "SelectionRule_1",
      "rule-action": "include",
      "object-locator": {
        "database-name": "sourceDB",
        "schema-name": "dbo",
        "table-name": "%"
      }
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "2",
      "rule-name": "2",
      "rule-action": "rename",
      "rule-target": "schema",
      "object-locator": {
        "database-name": "sourceDB",
        "schema-name": "dbo"
      },
      "value": "sourceDB_dbo"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it by removing the `"database-name"` element under the `"object-locator"` element. Tested first in AWS DMS directly with the edited JSON.

Revised TableMapping JSON is as follows -

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "rule-type": "selection",
      "rule-id": "1",
      "rule-name": "1",
      "rule-action": "include",
      "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "dbo",
        "table-name": "%"
      }
    },
    {
      "rule-type": "transformation",
      "rule-id": "2",
      "rule-name": "2",
      "rule-action": "rename",
      "rule-target": "schema",
      "object-locator": {
         "schema-name": "dbo"
      },
      "value": "sourceDB_dbo"
    }
  ]
}
```

I did rename the first rule name to "1" too.